# Fill missing values with new data R-Python

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have two dataset x and y

```
> x
   a index b
1  1     1 5
2 NA     2 6
3  2     3 NA
4 NA     4 9
> y
  index   a
1     2 100
2     4 101
>
```

I would like to fill the missing values of x with the values contained in y.

I have tried to use the merge function but the result is not what I want.

```
> merge(x,y, by = 'index', all=T)
  index a.x b a.y
1     1   1 5  NA
2     2  NA 6 100
3     3   2 7  NA
4     4  NA 9 101
```

In the real problem there are additional limitations:
1 - y does not fill all the missing values
2 - x and y have in common more  variables (so not only a and index)

EDIT :  More realistic example

```
> x
   a index  b  c
1  1     1  5 NA
2 NA     2  6 NA
3  2     3  NA  5
4 NA     4  9 NA
5 NA     5 10  6
> y
  index   a  c
1     2 100  4
2     4 101 NA
>
```

The solution would be accepted both in python or R

Comment: Could do something like `x$a[is.na(x$a)] <- y[na.omit(match(x$index, y$index)), "a"]`

Comment: `x$a[is.na(x$a)] <- y$a[y$index %in% x$index]` works for your example. But your "additional limitations" are not entirely clear. Please provide a minimal reproducible example of sufficient complexity - not more, not less.

Comment: @Henrik, it will give wrong result, if the index order in `x` will be different (for example `x$index <- c(1,4,3,2)`)

Comment: I have included an example closer to the original problem

Comment: @DavidArenburg, good point! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Donbeo In the tested example, all of them gave similar results.  Please let me know if it is not the case.

Comment: @akrun I have discovered that the data y has also some index that are not in the data x.  In this case your second method return an error while the first one seems to work. (not 100% sure yet)

Comment: @Donbeo If you can provide an example dataset that reproduces the error, I can take a look at it (preferably using `dput` i.e. `dput(head(data,20))`

Comment: @Donbeo In the "more realistic example", do you want to fill the NA's in the 2nd row and the first NA in the 4th row? For the rows that you don't have data in the second dataset you don't replace the NA in the first dataset, is this right?

Answer (score 0):

I used your `merge` idea and did the following using `dplyr`. I am sure there will be better ways of doing this task.

```
index <- 1:5
a <- c(1, NA, 2, NA, NA)
b <- c(5,6,NA,9,10)
c <- c(NA,NA,5,NA,6)
ana <- data.frame(index, a,b,c, stringsAsFactors=F)

index <- c(2,4)
a <- c(100, 101)
c <- c(4, NA)
bob <- data.frame(index, a,c, stringsAsFactors=F)

> ana
index  a  b  c
1     1  1  5 NA
2     2 NA  6 NA
3     3  2 NA  5
4     4 NA  9 NA
5     5 NA 10  6

> bob
  index   a  c
1     2 100  4
2     4 101 NA

ana %>%
    merge(., bob, by = "index", all = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(a.x = ifelse(a.x %in% NA, a.y, a.x)) %>%
    mutate(c.x = ifelse(c.x %in% NA, c.y, c.x))

  index a.x  b c.x a.y c.y
1     1   1  5  NA  NA  NA
2     2 100  6   4 100   4
3     3   2 NA   5  NA  NA
4     4 101  9  NA 101  NA
5     5  NA 10   6  NA  NA
```

I overwrote a.x (ana$$a) using a.y (bob$a) using `mutate`. I did a similar thing for c.x (ana$c). If you remove a.y and c.y in the end, that will be the outcome you expect, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xa = x[,c(1,2)]
m1 = merge(y,xa,all=T)
m1 = m1[!duplicated(m1$index),]
m1$b = x$b[match(m1$index, x$index)]
m1$c = x$c[match(m1$index, x$index)]

m1
  index   a  b  c
1     1   1  5 NA
2     2 100  6 NA
4     3   2 NA  5
5     4 101  9 NA
7     5  NA 10  6
```

or, if there many other columns like b and c:

```
xa = x[,c(1,2)]
m1 = merge(y,xa,all=T)
m1 = m1[!duplicated(m1$index),]
for(nn in names(x)[3:4]) m1[,nn] = x[,nn][match(m1$index, x$index)]
m1
  index   a  b  c
1     1   1  5 NA
2     2 100  6 NA
4     3   2 NA  5
5     4 101  9 NA
7     5  NA 10  6
```

Comment: This maybe solved the `a` and `c` problem, but completely messed up column `b`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have completely revised my solution.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple columns to replace, you could try converting from `wide` to `long` form as shown in the first two methods and replace in one step

```
 m1 <- merge(x,y, by="index", all=TRUE)
 m1L <- reshape(m1, idvar="index", varying=grep("\\.", colnames(m1)), direction="long", sep=".")
 row.names(m1L) <- 1:nrow(m1L)
 lst1 <- split(m1L, m1L$time)
 indx <- is.na(lst1[[1]][,4:5])
 lst1[[1]][,4:5][indx] <- lst1[[2]][,4:5][indx]
 res <- lst1[[1]][,c(4,1,2,5)]
 res
 #    a index  b  c
 #1   1     1  5 NA
 #2 100     2  6  4
 #3   2     3 NA  5
 #4 101     4  9 NA
 #5  NA     5 10  6
```

Or you could use `dplyr` with `tidyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)

  z <- left_join(x, y, by="index")  %>% 
            gather(Var, Val, matches("\\.")) %>%
             separate(Var, c("Var1", "Var2"))
  indx1 <- which(is.na(z$Val) & z$Var2=="x")
  z$Val[indx1] <- z$Val[indx1+nrow(z)/2]
  z %>%
    spread(Var1, Val) %>%
    filter(Var2=="x") %>% 
    select(-Var2)
  #  index  b   a  c
  #1     1  5   1 NA
  #2     2  6 100  4
  #3     3 NA   2  5
  #4     4  9 101 NA
  #5     5 10  NA  6
```

Or `split` the columns by matching `names` before the `.` and use `lapply` to replace the NA's.

```
 indx <- grep("\\.", colnames(m1),value=TRUE)
 res <- cbind(m1[!names(m1) %in% indx],
            sapply(split(indx, gsub("\\..*", "", indx)), function(x) {
                                             x1 <- m1[x]
                                             indx1 <- is.na(x1[,1])
                                             x1[,1][indx1] <- x1[,2][indx1]
                                             x1[,1]} ))
  res
  #  index  b   a  c
  #1     1  5   1 NA
  #2     2  6 100  4
  #3     3 NA   2  5
  #4     4  9 101 NA
  #5     5 10  NA  6
```

Comment: should this methods return all the same result?